# Function as a key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I'm having a multidimensional array in `PHP` and the following code:

```
<?php

    $weather = array (
        "AVAILABLE"  => array (
            "first" => "We're having a nice day.", 
            "second" => "We're not having a nice day.", 
            "fifth" => "It's raining out there.", 
            "tenth" => "It's gonna be warm today."));

    function getDomain() {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.com') !== FALSE) {
            return "first";
        }
        elseif (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.eu') !== FALSE) {
            return "second";
        }
        else {
            die();
        }
    }

    function myWeather($string) {
        $domain = getDomain();
        return $weather[$string][$domain];
    }

    echo myWeather("AVAILABLE");

?>
```

When I am at web with domain .com, it should echo value of key "AVAILABLE" in domains key ("first") - We're having a nice day.

When I'll be in site with domain .eu, it should write value of key "AVAILABLE", but in another domains key ("second") - We're not having a nice day.

How can I make this work please? Later there will be more keys in array `$weather`.

Comment: `myWeather` can't see the `$weather` array because it's defined outside of the function's scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add array as a ***parameter*** to the function `myWeather()`:-

```
<?php

$weather = array (
                "AVAILABLE"  => array (
                    "first" => "We're having a nice day.", 
                    "second" => "We're not having a nice day.", 
                    "fifth" => "It's raining out there.", 
                    "tenth" => "It's gonna be warm today."
                )
            );

function getDomain() {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.com') !== FALSE) {
        return "first";
    }
    elseif (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.eu') !== FALSE) {
        return "second";
    }
    else {
        return "fifth"; // instead of die(); return some value
    }
}

function myWeather($string,$array) {
    $domain = getDomain();
    return $array[$string][$domain];
}

echo myWeather("AVAILABLE",$weather);

?>
```

Note:- The above needed to make ***array available*** inside ***function scope***

Working output:-https://eval.in/841524